# Решение circular dependency в проекте на gradle + spring

Tags: java, spring, gradle, зависимости

Есть куча модулей, но нас интересуют два из них (назовем их М1 и М2).

На старте приложения, когда спринг инитит бины, классу из модуля М1 нужно в post construct методе получить данные от класса из модуля М2. Соответственно получаем зависимость М1 <- М2.

И тут образовывается проблема, потому что нам нужно сделать так, чтобы в другом классе М2 был доступ к другому классу из модуля М1 на стадии работы приложения. То есть нужна зависимость М2 <- М1, но тоогда получается та самая circular dependency

Что делать ?

Comment: Обычно эта проблема решается с помощью DI через сеттеры или ленивой инициализацией(@Lazy на @Bean методе).

Comment: @AntonSorokin дк градл даже не собирает это, потому что там circular dependency

Comment: @ValentynAnzhurov, ну значит это архитектурный косяк - вынесите то, что является камнем преткновения в отдельный подпроект и используйте его как implementation зависимость

Comment: @keekkenen можно на конкретно моем примере, чтобы вы оттуда вынесли ?

Comment: @ValentynAnzhurov, да, похоже, что я не вник в суть, вынести ничего не выйдет, следует, пойти по пути, что как выше написал Антон, либо рефакторить, чтобы не было циклических зависимостей

Answer (score 0):

Когда образуется круговая зависимость, то есть M1 библиотека(dependency) зависит от M2 библиотеки, а M2 зависит от M1 решения могут быть следующие:

1) Разрывать эту связь и убрать одну из зависимотей M1 от M2, или M2 от M1

2) Если M1 и M2 это ваши библиотеки, а не сторонние зависимоти, то можно просто объединить их в один модуль, то есть в одну зависимоть.